# Tensorflow partitioned csv input_fn

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, dask

The problem, to sum it up, is that I have the data I want to use for training split into a lot of smaller csvs(`feat-01.csv`, `feat-02.csv`, etc). I am trying to feed these to an `Estimator`, more exactly to do this via some sort of `input_fn`.

My ideal solution would've been to have some sort of input function that takes a `dask.Dataframe`(which is pretty much how I generated my data until now) and batch it to the estimator. I tried something along these lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv('feat-*.csv')
tf.contrib.learn.extract_dask_data(ddf)
```

However this fails with:

```
TypeError: Expected `meta` to specify type DataFrame, got type Index
```

I kinda gave up on this idea due to the lack of documentation about using dask directly, although some docstrings seem to point out that it should be possible. I was thinking about making an `input_fn` to feed it directly from the csv files, but I found no specific examples about this usecase either.

Being a bit of TF noob, I was wondering what the cleanest method to accomplish is.

Comment: The hyphen between 'feat' and '*' will throw an error in Python.  Underscore will not. Have tried renaming a file to test?  You may even be able to delete the hyphen and let the wildcard take care of the hyphen though I can't I don't know (and can't test) if that is the behavior.

Comment: @Rookie This is not the case here, the `Dataframe` is built ok. Also I'm pretty sure hyphens are not a problem when opening files in general in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After trying fruitlessly to implement it via `dask` I gave up on the idea both from frustration and because the overhead might be a little to much.

I implemented an input function using tf's queues with pretty good results. Here is [the code](https://gist.github.com/nikitautiu/3aea0e8ce77f0cd9da9a89ab0b30a48f). Although slightly more complicated than what I had in mind with simply passing dataframes to the the estimator, but doing all the work inside tensorflow seems the most elegant approach.

**FINAL UPDATE:**
Shortly after I posted this question tensorlfow 1.4 was released, and with it the dataset API was officially supported and better documented. If anyone is still interested in this question, I advise you to check out [this paragraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data) from the TF documentation.